# Python Namespace package as extension to existing package

Tags: python, namespaces, pip, setuptools, pypi

Is it possible to add something to namespace/path of existing package which is not a namespace package?

Lets say a have a extisting external package named `package`.

I use it in my `project.py` like this:

```
from package.module import Class
```

Is it possible to create package called `extension` to namespace of `package` so its importable from `package.extension`?

```
from package.module import Class
from package.extension.module import ExtensionClass
```

Is it possible to just install both packages using `pip`/`setuptools` without adding monkey patches into my `project.py` in which I want to import from both `package` and `package.extension`?

---

### Partial Solution

I've been able to achieve what I need in two ways: by modifying original `package` and by monkey patching in `project.py`

Structure:

```
./test.py
./demo/test.py
./demo/__init__.py
./extension/demo/__init__.py
./extension/demo/extension/test.py
./extension/demo/extension/__init__.py
./extension/__init__.py
```

Contents of `./test.py`:

```
import demo.test
demo.test.hello()

import demo.extension.test
demo.extension.test.hello()
```

### Partial Solution 1 - modify original package

I've modified `demo/__init__.py` so it contains:

```
import pkgutil

__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Execution example:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=extension
$ python test.py 
Hello! I'm demo.
Hello! I'm extension.
```

---

### Partial Solution 2 - modify original package

I've modified `./test.py` so it contains monkey patch:

```
import pkgutil
import demo
demo.__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(demo.__path__, demo.__name__)

import demo.test
demo.test.hello()

import demo.extension.test
demo.extension.test.hello()
```

Execution example:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=extension
$ python test.py 
Hello! I'm demo.
Hello! I'm extension.
```

### The problem (again)

One of the solution requires the owner of original package to allow extensions, the other solution requires monkey patching. Is there a possibility that package installed via setup.py/pip will not require chaning of original package or monkey patching?

Answer (score 2):

I gather that namespace packages are a feature of setuptools and [the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#namespace-packages) only state two conditions:

- `namespace_packages` in `setup()` and
- `__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)` in your
  `__init__.py` files.

With that, I've tested following configuration using Python 3.3 on Windows 7:

```
│   setup.py
│
└───cherrypy
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───extend
        │   test.py
        │
        └───__init__.py
```

My setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = "HelloWorld",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages(),
    namespace_packages = ['cherrypy']
)
```

Then, after `python setup.py develop`, cherrypy.extend works like a module and I'm able to load classes from it:

```
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:37:12) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cherrypy
>>> cherrypy
<module 'cherrypy' from 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\cherrypy\\__init__.py
'>
>>> from cherrypy.extend import Cls
>>> from cherrypy.extend import test
>>> test
<module 'cherrypy.extend.test' from 'c:\\users\\me\\desktop\\test\\cherrypy\
\extend\\test.py'>
>>> o = Cls()
>>> o
<cherrypy.extend.Cls object at 0x01AA0AB0>
>>>
```

I haven't tested installability with pip, but there doesn't seem to be anything to make it impossible. If this doesn't work for you, and/or you're in different environment, please let us know.

EDIT: I note that I ran Python from the source folder of my package and it loaded from ./ . This still works as expected and I swapped example above for one where I'm using other working directory.

Answer (score 1):

This may be not too helpful, but you can check [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and some of [its extensions](http://flask.pocoo.org/extensions/) sources. Flask extensions works exactly like you describe, eg.:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Comment: Flask explicitely allows for extensions: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/ext/__init__.py